# How transclude works with isolate scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written this snippet of code.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.hobby='AngularJS';
});

app.directive('outputText',function(){
  return {
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div output-text>
     <p>Hello {{name}}</p>
   </div>
   <div output-text>
     <p>I love {{hobby}}!!</p>
   </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see above I am using isolate scope for my directive where there is no name property in the isolate scope. But how it is accessing the parent scope name property, As I am not even using child scope or I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transcluded element is always bound to the parent scope, irrespective of whether you are using isolated or not.

This is what the [documentation on transclude](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/service/$compile) states

> **transclude**
>
> compile the content of the element and make it available to
> the directive. Typically used with ngTransclude. The advantage of
> transclusion is that the linking function receives a transclusion
> function which is pre-bound to the correct scope. In a typical setup
> the widget creates an isolate scope, but the transclusion is not a
> child, but a sibling of the isolate scope. This makes it possible for
> the widget to have private state, and the transclusion to be bound to
> the parent (pre-isolate) scope.

Comment: So this means the trancluded element always have access to parent scope?

Comment: Yes that is true. If you want the html to be part of isolated scope define it in the directive template.

Comment: `If you want the html to be part of isolated scope define it in the directive template` Could you please explain me how?

Comment: What @Chandermani means is that in the directive definition object (the one that the directive function returns) you can specify a `template` or a `templateUrl` property - that template would be bound to the isolate scope.

Answer (score 0):

Every directive is compiled and linked to a scope.  Transcluded contents are always linked to the directive's immediate outside scope (although, this is overridable by using the transclude function - 5th arg to your link function).  In your case, it is the MainCtrl controller's scope.

If your directive was inside of an ng-repeat (or another directive that creates a child scope), then the transcluded contents would be linked against the ng-repeat's child scope.